# Reading integers and double from .txt file which also contains strings

Tags: c++, string, parsing, ifstream

I want to write a program that reads lines of text from a file.  Each line contains several strings, one integer and one double value. The number of lines is not known in advance (i.e., the program needs to read lines until end of file) and the length of each line is not known as well.
The while loop checks if the line ordered in following manner:

```
 --  string -- integer -- double --- string  
Cat.     3:           18.00 Kr.       [ Tvål ]    
Cat.     1:           14.50 Kr.       [ Äppelmos Bob ]     
Cat.     1:           12.00 Kr.       [ Coca Cola 2 lit. ]     
Cat.     1:           18.00 Kr.       [ Kroppkakor 4 st. ]
```

The problem is the last string contains  several spaces, so the program does not take it as a one entire string. The last string is accepted like several strings and I see on  my screen only **Cat.     3:           18.00 Kr.** instead of whole list of lines.

I tried to handle program like this:

```
double doubleValue;

int intValue;

string str1, str2, str3;

ifstream infile("Register.txt", ifstream::in);

while (infile >> str1 >> intValue >> str2 >> doubleValue >> str3)
{   
   cout << intValue << " " << doubleValue << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is slightly off topic.. 4 kroppkakor for 18 kr is a pretty nice deal.

Comment: you should probably look in the direction of reading line by line and using regular expressions (`std::regex`) to get the data from it - solving things like 'one ore more spaces' is bascially what regex is maded for

Comment: You're going to need more sophisticated line parsing.  Try looking for the `:` and for the `[` and `]` characters.  That will much more reliably delimit your input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working, thanks to **herohuyongtao**. 
This is a full code snippet that allows to read .txt file which contains strings, integers, doubles and print only integer and double values.
This is a part from a txt file.

```
Cat.     3:           14.50 Kr.       [ Äppelmos Bob ]     
Cat.     2:           12.00 Kr.       [ Coca Cola 2 lit. ]     
Cat.     5:           18.00 Kr.       [ Kroppkakor 4 st. ]

..........

..........
```

Solution is below.

```
    using namespace std;

        cout << "Category totals for last opening period: " << endl;

        double doubleValue;
        int intValue;
        string line, str, str2, str3;

        ifstream infile("Register.txt", ifstream::in);
        getline(infile, line);

        while (getline(infile, line))
        {   
            stringstream infile(line);
            infile >> str >> intValue >> str2 >> doubleValue;
            getline(infile, str3);
            cout << endl;

                cout << setw(3) << str << setw(1) << intValue << setw(7)                                                 << str2 << doubleValue << str3;
        cout << endl;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) will stop parsing at white spaces.

To work out, you can read the whole line first by using [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Then, parse the first four parts (by applying [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)), and finally get the remaining part by calling [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) again.

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string line;
while (getline(infile, line)) // read the whole line from the file
{
    stringstream ss(line);
    ss >> str1 >> intValue >> str2 >> doubleValue; // pause the first four parts
    getline(ss, str3); // parse the remaining part to str3, e.g. "Kr. [ Tvål ]"
}
```

Comment: it's working, thanks a lot. This es code goes through file, reads first four parts, then parse's the remaining string. The contents are printed out in the same way, just "cout <<" is added.

Comment: @user3578809 Sure, you can do anything you want after you get the data. :P

Answer (score 2):

you could always use fscanf, it will let you, as long as you know the format:

```
fscanf(f, "%s %d [ %[^\x5D]\x5D %lf", str1, &int1, str2, &double1);
```

I personally prefer scanf, here is a simple table:

```
fmt   meaning
%s    non-whitespace string
%d    integer
%u    unsigned integer
%ld   long
%lu   unsigned long
%f    float
%lf   double
%llf  long double
```

It also handles special formats as well, but that is beyond the scope of this. But its useful if you say have a file like this:

```
30.1 multi word string
```

you can read it by

```
scanf("%lf %[^\n]\n", &mydouble, strbuf);
```

Preference is key here, but I recommend you use fscanf for it

```
fscanf(FILE *f, char *fmt, ...);
```

http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fscanf/

Comment: I put the example in there: fscanf(f, "%s %d %s %lf", str1, &int1, str2, &double1); will read it

Comment: The input is string, int, double, string. And there's embedded whitespace and other characters.

Comment: there is embedded whitespace inside the strings?

Comment: Well it looks like it to me. See the sample input in the question.